Using present simple in conditionals
Is using present simple  in conditional sentences sometimes a little ambiguous in meaning?

I will wash my teeth if I give her a kiss

Here, I want to say that I will brush my teeth before kissing. Yet, I think both meanings are possible it might also mean that she's dirty and I'm gonna wash my mouth after the kiss. Is that correct? Does it depend on context?

Sadly yes, your sentence is ambiguous as it does not specify the order in which the actions take place. To avoid this you could say:

Before / After I kiss her I will brush my teeth.

or

If I am going to kiss her I will brush my teeth first.

or

Once I've kissed her I will (have to) brush my teeth.

depending on the situation.
